# Linear Alegbra - inverse matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a general question.

If there is a matrix which is inverse and I multiply it by other matrixs which are inverse.
Will the result already be reverse matrix?

My intonation says is correct, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the question "is the product of invertible matrices invertible?"

Comment: Use that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ and that $A$ has inverse iff $\det(A)\ne 0.$

Comment: @GitGud Yea, but with different invertible matrixs. 

Not the inverse of a specific matrix. because $A*(A-1)=I$ which is clear, The question is for all inverse matrixs.

Comment: Let $A,B$ be invertible matrices. You're asking if $AB$ is invertible. Well, try multiplying by the matrix $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ on both sides separately and see what happens.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Will you please edit & explain your question more..

Comment: 'If there is a matrix which is inverse' means what?? Which has inverse or anything else..

Comment: @user152715 Maybe I use the wrong term in English, I mean that the matrix has an opposing matrix, for exmaple if A is inverse matrix then A*B=I (B is the opposing matrix of A), The question is if I take matrix A and multiply it by any inverse matrix I still get inverse matrix, hope it clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A,B$ be invertible matrices, then $\det(A)\neq0$ and $\det(B)\neq0$. Then obviously, $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)\neq0$, therefore $AB$ is an invertible matrix.

Answer (score 1):

For any invertible $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, $(AB)^{−1}$ = $B^{−1}A^{−1}$.
You may prove that statement by definition of matrix inverse and matrix multiplication.